# How to frame unevenly a heading?

Tags: templates, framed

The image below shows a textual template that I am working on and which has been produced with the MWE code listing.

[image]

I would prefer the heading to be 'boxed in' as shown in the figure below which is from an annual report that was probably typeset with InDesign. It is easy to compete with Word but a bit harder with InDesign.

[image]

How can I box the heading using TikZ or Plain TeX or LaTeX? Please use LuaLateX to compile. The code is a bit rough, as I am parameterizing to work through options to be set via a Lua Table.

The not so MWE.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,multicol,xcolor,calc,lipsum,lettrine}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\definecolor{spot}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\definecolor{theblue} {rgb}{0.02,0.04,0.48}
\definecolor{thegrey} {gray}{0.5}
\definecolor{thegray} {gray}{0.5}
\def\ZZZ{\phantom{ZZZ}}
\makeatletter
\def\HHUGE{\@setfontsize\HHUGE{58}{67}\selectfont}
\makeatother
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
  calc,%
  backgrounds,%
  fadings,%
  positioning,%
   }

\usepackage[bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{ %
 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
 \node [xshift=0cm,yshift=-1.5cm] at (current page.north west)
[text width=\paperwidth, text=white ,text height=1.5cm, shade, left color=spot!50!white, right color=white, above right]
{
\hbox to 1cm{\hfill \textbf{\thepage}}
\vspace*{1em}
};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \color{white}}

\begin{document}

\makebox[\textwidth]{\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
\columnseprule2pt
\def\columnseprulecolor{\color{thegray}}
\columnsep22pt
\begin{multicols}{2}

\color{theblue}
\flushright
\Large
\obeylines
Over the last year we
have continued to
develop and improve the
range of funding schemes
we offer to meet the
needs of the arts and
humanities communities,
for example, by offering
opportunities for early
career researchers.
\columnbreak
\color{thegray}

\small
\flushleft

\obeylines
We have engaged both
individuals and groups to
build a vision for our strategic
initiatives and our museums
and galleries strategy, have
opened up opportunities
for the arts and humanities
in cross-Council funding
initiatives and undertaken
to represent the needs of our
communities in arenas such
as the Research Councils’
project on the Efficiency and
Effectiveness of Peer Review
Journals
initiatives and undertaken
to represent the needs of our
communities in arenas such
as the Research Councils’
project on the Efficiency and
Effectiveness of Peer Review
Journals
\end{multicols}
\end{minipage}
}
\bigskip
\bgroup


\fboxsep20pt\color{thegray!60}
\hspace*{-1.85cm}\fbox{\HHUGE Research}

\bigskip
\egroup
\raggedright
\begin{multicols}{2}
\color{black!80}

\parindent1em
\lettrine{L}{ipsum} \lipsum[1-3]
\end{multicols}

\newpage

\hspace*{-2.2cm}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth+2cm}
\columnseprule2pt
\def\columnseprulecolor{\color{spot!50!white}}
\columnsep22pt
\begin{multicols}{2}
\color{theblue}
\flushright
\LARGE
\obeylines
One of the challenges in
the area of knowledge
transfer is to identify
models of opportunity
for engagement.
\columnbreak
\color{thegray}

\large
\flushleft

\obeylines
Opportunities that build trust between
researchers and other partners; enable
an exchange of knowledge and ideas that
benefit both; and encourage novel forms
of engagement that permit academic and
non-academic partners to maximize their
contribution to the nation’s cultural, social
and economic life. 
\rule{0cm}{1cm}
\end{multicols}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\bgroup
\fboxsep3pt\fboxrule0pt\color{spot!50!white}
\hskip\dimexpr-\leftmargin-\hoffset\relax\fbox{\HHUGE\color{spot!50!white} Postgraduate}
\definecolor{head}{rgb}{173,216,230}
\makebox[\textwidth+\leftmargin]{\HHUGE\ZZZ \color{spot!50!white}Programmes\hfill}
\egroup

\bigskip
\parindent1em


\begin{multicols}{2}
\lettrine{P}{ost}  \lipsum
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: trivial observations ... (1) a bit more vertical space between lines of the main title.  (2) your two columns are (together) centered; the ones in the indesign version are intentionally shifted more to the right, and the top matter, more to the left, for an asymmetric layout.  (3) the second line of the main title should probably end more to the left -- a tall order with such a long word -- so that the vertical rule at the right of the title (when you get one) doesn't go (very far) past the right-hand margin of the text; in fact, that rule seems to define the margin in the indesign example.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. It still needs a lot of work and I am not calculating any dimensions at present or checking for odd or even pages (I will add them when I am done with the Lua code) then everything will be adjustable. You right with your observations.

Comment: NOTE that `head` color will result in white, I think. [hyperref - XColor - Specifying Color in RGB or CYMK does not work correctly - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586350/xcolor-specifying-color-in-rgb-or-cymk-does-not-work-correctly)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you load the `tikzmark` library, you could do something like this (with some tidying up):

```
  \bigskip
  \tikzmark{p0}

  {\fboxsep3pt\fboxrule0pt\color{spot!50!white}
  \hskip\dimexpr-\leftmargin-\hoffset\relax\fbox{\HHUGE\color{spot!50!white}\tikzmark{p3}Postgraduate\tikzmark{p1}}
  \definecolor{head}{rgb}{173,216,230}
  \makebox[\textwidth+\leftmargin]{\HHUGE\ZZZ \color{spot!50!white}\tikzmark{p4}Programmes\tikzmark{p2}\hfill}
  }

  \tikzmark{p6}
  \bigskip
  \parindent1em

  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, color=spot!50!white, line width=\fboxrule]
    \draw ({pic cs:p0} -| current page.west) +(0,5pt) -| ([yshift=-10pt,xshift=5pt]{pic cs:p1}) -| ([xshift=5pt]{pic cs:p2})  |- ({pic cs:p4} |- {pic cs:p6}) -| ([yshift=-5pt, xshift=-5pt]{pic cs:p4}) |- ([yshift=-20pt]{pic cs:p3}) coordinate (p7) -- (p7 -| current page.west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: boxed title]

The `tikzpagenodes` package may also be useful for aligning the right of the title with the right margin, if that is desired.

Comment: Thanks. This did the job. The right alignment does not worry me, as I am calculating all the lengths. I am also trying to figure a good algo for short and long words.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Glad it helped. I suggested that in light of comments on your question because the package provides nodes for e.g. the text area etc. However, trying to align things right in that way might not be a good idea if you have title words of very variable lengths!

Answer (score 1):

Is it fine using TeX's rule and boxes?
Something along the lines of

```
\raisebox{-0.5ex}{\rule{0.25pt}{1ex}}%    %% not inside the content box, hence need to add the raisebox
  \makebox[10cm]{\makebox[0cm]{%          %% in a 0pt box to superpose all 3 boxes
    blablatruc%                           %% one part of the title
  }%
  \raisebox{2.5ex}{\makebox[0pt]{\rule{3cm}{0pt}\rule{7cm}{0.25pt}}}% %% upper rule, part without "ink", part with it. Ratio should be determined automatically from the space left after the first part / before the second part
  \raisebox{-0.5ex}{\makebox[0pt]{\rule{10cm}{0.25pt}}}}%             %% lower rule
\vrule                                    %% closing rule
```

This example frame the second part with something like this:

```
      ----------+
|               |
+---------------+
```