# XColor - Specifying Color in RGB or CYMK does not work correctly

Tags: hyperref, color

I have tried using `xcolor` to specify a color. Here is my code:

```
 \xglobal\definecolor{my_green}{rgb}{56,99,113}
```

However, this does not work and shows as white. I am using a MAC and have also used the color picker program on mac OS and used numbers for RGB and sRGB but still no luck. Specifying in CMYK does not work either.

Comment: I think it's because when you use `rgb` you need to define the values from 0 to 1. So in your case you need to divide 56,99 and 113 by 256. Then use that number. To achieve format from 0 to 255 you need to use the key `RGB`, if I remember properly

Comment: Related question, [color - RGB colour macro: is it possible to divide by 255 in Latex? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102317/rgb-colour-macro-is-it-possible-to-divide-by-255-in-latex)

Comment: Almost the same as [Beamer: change header background color - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360307/beamer-change-header-background-color) although the other one also make an unrelated error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use RGB (uppercase), lowercase rgb expects percentages (values between 0 and 1).
This definitely works for me:

```
\definecolor{my_green}{RGB}{56,99,113}
```